# SQL Server: Inserting empty value (zero-arity INSERT)

Tags: sql-server, insert

I made test table:

```
create table tmp (id BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY)
```

Now I want to insert a value:

```
insert into tmp () values();
```

and it complains:

```
SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

I cannot insert ID, because it fails with:

```
insert into tmp (id) values(1);
-- SQL Error [544] [S0001]: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column
-- in table 'tmp' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

`DEFAULT` syntax for `VALUES` is also forbidden:

```
insert into tmp values(default);
-- SQL Error [8101] [S0001]: An explicit value for the identity column in table 'tmp'
-- can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is the `tmp` table supposed to be used as some sort of counter?...because there already are objects that exist to be used as counters, such as Sequences.

Comment: But see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/67808746/14868997

Comment: @J.D. It is more a theoretical question - I tested `alter ... default 0 not null` and needed the simplest temporary table signature.

Comment: @Charlieface First reference answers the question... I didn't know IDENTITY is something special...

Comment: `IDENTITY` isn't special, it's just another type of `DEFAULT` constraint. The same thing can be done with any table with defaults on all columns (even `NULL` as the default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
INSERT INTO tmp
DEFAULT VALUES;
```

To explicitly specify the column name,in particular cases, try with `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` 
(1. and don't forget do set it back to off `SET IDENTITY_INSERT tmp OFF` )

(2. the value you provide for `id` column, because it's primary key, should be unique):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tmp ON
INSERT INTO tmp(id)
VALUES(898989)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tmp OFF
```

All Script :

```
create table tmp (id BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO tmp
DEFAULT VALUES;

SELECT *
FROM tmp;
```

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XYtGk5aA)

Comment: Great! I updated the question with alternative `default` syntax which doesn't work....

Comment: @gavenkoa, you should try with `INSERT INTO tmp  DEFAULT VALUES;`

Comment: Your solution is working, I just told that I worked with a different one and it conflicts with `IDENTITY`.